# Python requests Json body includes some thai values, needs to be encoded as it is

Tags: python, json, character-encoding, python-requests, thai

I have some json containing some `thai` values. It looks something like

```
{
   "TitleName": "คุณ",
   "FirstName": "Simar"
}
```

I need to make a Http POST request with this json body with the exact `thai` value.I am using Python 3 `requests` library to make the request.
I tried this

```
headers = {
        'Content-Type': "application/json",
        'Authorization': "xxx",
        'cache-control': "no-cache",
        'Postman-Token': "xxx"
    }    
response = requests.request("POST", url, json=request, headers=headers)
```

It generates json values as

```
"TitleName": "\\u0e04\\u0e38\\u0e13",
"FirstName": "Simar"
```

I also tried this

```
json_request = json.dumps(self.request_data,ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')     
response = requests.request("POST", url, json=json_request, headers=headers)
```

It generates json values as

```
"TitleName": "\xe0\xb8\x84\xe0\xb8\xb8\xe0\xb8\x93",
"FirstName": "Simar"
```

But I want json values to be generated as

```
   "TitleName": "คุณ",
   "FirstName": "Simar"
```

Help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to keep it as is? I think Python does not print weird characters (like emojis), that does not mean you cannot use it on a website.

Comment: In JSON, \u0e04 is the same character as คุ. (Is \\u0e04 just a Python literal representation of a text string that happens to contain JSON, perhaps as shown by a debugger?)

Comment: I want to keep it as it is, because the API which I want to hit works only with the thai value, and not with the literals like "\u0e04" or "\xe0"

Comment: @TomBlodget yes I picked this value from the debugger

Comment: Thanks for explaining.  \x notation is not valid JSON but \u is. Too bad your client is non-compliant.  I don't have a better solution than @snakecharmerb (but others might).

Answer (score 0):

To preserve non-ascii characters in POST requests you need to serialise to json manually, and explicitly set the `content-type` header.

```
data = json.dumps(my_dict, ensure_ascii=False)
r = requests.post(url, headers={'content-type': 'application/json'},
                  data=data.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: I think I did the same thing already as mentioned in the question. But it gives me the value as
"TitleName": "\xe0\xb8\x84\xe0\xb8\xb8\xe0\xb8\x93"

Comment: Can you try setting the header as `'application/json;charset=utf8'`?  You have got similar code in your question, but requests requires that you set the content-type header when doing this, and you question doesn't show which headers you're sending.

Comment: I already tried with header as `'application/json'` and also with `'application/json; charset=utf8'`. But none of it worked.

Comment: Also, I have edited the question to specify the headers used.